# Scraping Data with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

i'm trying to scrape a movie names from my Vudu Movie List into a csv file. Im at the early stages, and i can't figure out how to use BeautifulSoup to get the name. I know where its located in the html on the website. I have it set to print the location now, but all it returns in "None".

I have included my code progress so far and a photo of the html code from the website that i need. Thanks to anyone who helps!

```
##Make sure to replace USERNAME and PASSWORD with your own username and password

#Import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import json
import re
import requests
import time
import urllib.request

#Login Information
USERNAME = "example"
PASSWORD = "example"

#URLs
login_url = "https://my.vudu.com/MyLogin.html?type=sign_in&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vudu.com%2F"
url = "https://www.vudu.com/movies/#my_vudu/my_movies"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    browser.get('https://my.vudu.com/MyLogin.html?type=sign_in&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vudu.com%2F')

    time.sleep(10)

    username = browser.find_element_by_name('email')
    password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')

    username.send_keys(USERNAME)
    password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.custom-button').click()

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    name_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'gwt-Label title'})

    print (name_box)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the content is not dynamically loaded with javascript?

Comment: <img class="gwt-Image" src="https://images2.vudu.com/poster2/132100-m" alt="10,000 B.C.">

Comment: The first title is 10,000 B.C.

Comment: so i feel like there is a way to do it using this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urllib.request.urlopen(url)` (and `requests.get(url)`) gets `HTML` direcetly from server and it means it doesn't have element added by JavaScript in web browser. And also it is not logged in.

But you user `Selenium` which load page and runs JavaScript and you can get HTML with all changes from `browser.page_source` and use in

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

Question is why to use `BeautifulSoup` if `Selenium` has functions `find_*` to seach on page.

---

**EDIT:** example which uses methods in `Selenium` and `BeautifulSoup`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

#chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
#browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get("https://www.vudu.com/")
time.sleep(1)

print('--- Selenium ---')

all_images = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.border .gwt-Image')
for image in all_images[:5]: # first five elements
    #print('image:', image.get_attribute('src'))
    print('alt:', image.get_attribute('alt'))

print('--- BeautifulSoup ---')

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

all_images = soup.select('.border .gwt-Image')
for image in all_images[:5]: # first five elements
    #print('image:', image['src'])
    print('alt:', image['alt'])
```

Result:

```
--- Selenium ---
alt: It (2017)
alt: American Made
alt: Dunkirk
alt: mother!
alt: The LEGO NINJAGO Movie
--- BeautifulSoup ---
alt: It (2017)
alt: American Made
alt: Dunkirk
alt: mother!
alt: The LEGO NINJAGO Movie
```

Comment: if i were to use selenium how would i do it with that specific data i want?

Comment: Selenium has many functions `find_element_by_*` (for first element) and `find_elements_by_*` (for many elements)  like `find_elements_by_class_name('gwt-Label')` or `find_elements_by_css_selector('div.gwt-Label.title')` or `find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="gwt-Label title"]')`. Read documentation: [4.Locating Elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: see example in answer